# JavaFX in Eclipse Kepler: New FXML Document option is missing

Tags: eclipse, javafx

I do not have an option to choose JavaFx FXML Document everytime I attempt to create a new FXML Document (right click on package -> new - > other -> JavaFX) using Eclipse Kepler IDE. Also, I have an e(fx)clipse installed already. I want to try out this tutorial [http](https://blogs.oracle.com/jeromec/entry/integrating_javafx_scene_builder_in).

Edit:
Refer to this [image](http://oi60.tinypic.com/30b19na.jpg)

Comment: How have you installed e(fx)clipse?

Comment: Hi @user714965! Thanks for your reply. I followed the instructions here [link](http://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/install.html#for-the-ambitious)

Comment: So what entries do you see? Show a screenshot!

Comment: @tomsontom, Hi. Please check this [image](http://oi60.tinypic.com/30b19na.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reinstalling your e(fx)clipse plugin, or you can download an eclipse that comes with the plugin from ***[here](http://efxclipse.bestsolution.at/install.html#all-in-one)***

Comment: Hi @ItachiUchiha. Thanks for your reply. I tried the eclipse from your [link](http://efxclipse.bestsolution.at/install.html#all-in-one) and it worked (New FXML Document option is there). But I'm still wondering why [this](http://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/install.html#for-the-ambitious) installation guide did not work for me. There were no error logs, but the New FXML Doc option is simply missing ([image](http://oi60.tinypic.com/30b19na.jpg)). Anyway, I'll just use the IDE from your link. Thanks again.